# Error generating signed apk (unsigned apk works fine)

Tags: android

No idea why i am getting this error while generating the signed apk.
unsigned apk works fine.

My project build gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.fabits.fabits"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {

    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
    compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.github.john990:WaveView:v0.9'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error that i am getting gradle build

```
Warning:org.slf4j.LoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
Warning:org.slf4j.MDC: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder
Warning:org.slf4j.MarkerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder
Warning:there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

there is no codes added in proguard-rules.pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this line in your proguard-rules.pro file.

-dontwarn org.slf4j.**

-dontwarn javax.xml.**

-dontwarn org.apache.**

Comment: How did you decided to put these packages.

Comment: I face the same error earlier so, i do research on Proguard regarding this and found on google so i got the answer.If you learn proguard how it work you get little idea about it :). After giving the answer I thought you are facing one more error like multidex error but you are not facing that.Are you implementing multidex?

Comment: but now my signed apk is not installing on devices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142712/discussion-between-andy-developer-and-codenut).

Comment: @codenut which os it is not installing.In 7.0 right?